# Access Denied S3 with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting acquainted with using S3 with ruby to upload files to Amazon Web Service.  I recently was confronted with the following error: `AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied`.  In poking around on google, I found [this post](http://rexstjohn.com/how-to-solve-access-denied-with-heroku-paperclip-s3-ror/) on the error.  It claims that the bucket policies aren't sufficient to allow access via the web-app and that the user must be given "Administrator Access" as well.

I've given this a try and it works fine but I feel like this is an indication that I'm not doing it right, given that administrator access isn't mentioned in any other documentation I've read.  I'm using the aws-sdk gem.  Could anyone weigh in on whether admin access is necessary?  Many thanks!

Comment: you should not really need the `Admin Access` to achieve this. Do you have AWS `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` setup in your heroku config? You just need to make sure your user account has an “Access Policy” set in the IAM Console. See this for some more info: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam  Thanks for the response!  I'm actually not trying this on Heroku yet; I'm just working off my localhost.  I think I'm missing the necessary "Access Policy" in the IAM Console.  Which policy should I assign to the user?  `AmazonsS3FullAccess?`

Comment: yeah, that should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not really need the `Admin Access` to achieve this. 
Make sure you have AWS `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` setup in your heroku config. And, you also would need to make sure your user account has an `Access Policy` set in the AWS IAM Console.

See [this post](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3) for some more info.

The default permission for Paperclip is `:public_read` unless you specify the bucket to be private.

See this for information about [Module: Paperclip::Storage::S3](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

Comment: Ended up setting AmazonS3FullAccess for the user and it worked like a charm.  If I was partitioning with other buckets, I figure I could hone the policy more precisely by creating a custom one but this will work for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

None of the existing answers actually state which policies you need to grant, so here they are: `s3:PutObject`, `s3:DeleteObject`, and `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

Here's the complete S3 bucket policy I'm using to allow Paperclip to put objects with the `:public_read` permission:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_USER_ID:user/IAM_USER_NAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the accepted answer, you should not need "Admin Access". However, the typical policy for giving access to a bucket, as documented in some examples given by Amazon, could not be enough for paperclip.

The following policy worked for me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-to-be-set-by-you"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-to-be-set-by-you/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked great for me. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/92239/guillermo